# Setup JavaScript date in french

Tags: javascript, date, parsing, localization, formatting

I don't know JS at all but I need to use some code that would display the current date into french using the format below.

Examples :

- Assuming we're 21/10/2016, it should display "21ème jour du mois d'octobre".
- Assuming we're 25/12/2016, it should display "25ème jour du mois de décembre".
- Assuming we"re 01/08/2016, it should display "1er jour du mois d'août".

In France we're using months numbers :

- 1**er** jour.
- 2**ème** to 31**ème** jour.

In France we're using months :

- de janvier
- de février
- de mars
- de avril
- de mai
- de juin
- de juillet
- d'août
- de septembre
- d'octobre
- de novembre
- de décembre

I can't find anything on the internet for that... Do you have any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: I've checked it out and it doesn't allow that...

Comment: Just write it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know French, but the following should get you started:

```js
function frenchDate(date) {
  // Array of month names
  var months = ['de janvier', 'de f&eacute;vrier', 'de mars', 'd&acute;avril', 'de mai', 'de juin', 'de juillet',
                'd&acute;ao&ucirc;t', 'de septembre', 'd&acute;octobre', 'de novembre', 'de d&eacute;cembre'];
  // Get the day number from the date
  var dayNum = date.getDate();
  // Work out which ordinal to use
  var ord = dayNum == 1? 'er jour du mois ' : '&eacute;me jour du mois ';
  // Build the string and return it
  return dayNum + ord + months[date.getMonth()];
}

document.write(frenchDate(new Date()) + '<br>');

for (var d=1, m=0, y=2016; m<12; d++,m++) {
  document.write(d + '/' + (m+1) + '/' + y + ' : ' +
                 frenchDate(new Date(2016,m,d)) + '<br>');
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: geneva, sans-serif;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fear you have to implement it by hand, but to get it started I would suggest you to give a look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), It could be a nice starting point.

You can escape strings with [], adding the part you want into the basic format like: moment().format( "Do [ hello! this is escaped! ] YYYY")

```
    function convertDate( date ) {

        // "Do" automatically adds "er", but not "ème"
        var day_part = ( date.getDate() > 1 ) ? "ème" : "";

        // I don't speak french so I assume the following:
        // d': avril, août, octobre (4, 8 ,10 respectively)
        // de: other months
        var month_part = ( [ 4, 8, 10 ].includes( date.getMonth() +1 ) ) ? "d'" : "de";

        var f = "Do["+ day_part +" jour du mois "+ month_part +"] MMMM";

        return moment( date ).format( f );
    }
```

Comment: I wrote a formatter that allows anything in the format string, you just have to quote any character sequence that looks like a format token, so `'T\\he do \\da\\y of MMMM'` would be "The 25th day of October" or whatever.  ;-)